# Is the monkey the only hardware engineer you can hire?

Tags: game-dev-story

I wanted to make my own console, so I tried hiring several times in the last 5 years of my game, using the most expensive options. I never saw any hardware engineers until the escaped monkey was announced and appeared in the applicants list. At that point, the game was almost over.

**Is the monkey the only hardware engineer you can hire, or is it possible to hire others, earlier?** Perhaps it's just the luck of who applies?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If an employee is level 5 in Coder, Writer, Designer, and Sound Engineer, you can then train them as a Director or Producer.

If they are level 5 in Director and Producer as well, you can make them a Hardware Engineer.

The limiting factor here is that after so many level-ups, their salary will be very high (2 million dollars or more).

As far as I know, this is the only way to get a Hardware Engineer early in the game.

Comment: Also, once they are a level 5 Hardware Engineer, they are then able to switch to Hacker. But the same rules apply getting to this point can quickly put you into the hole.

Comment: also you need to not spend any knowledge cards till 2nd office then lv up anyone to lv 5 (100K salary) then switch their jobs to hardware engineer then if u lv them up to 10 (alot of salary) then they can become a hacker then further updates will tell us whats next

Answer (score 2):

One way to get a hardware engineer is to level an employee up to level 5, then change their job to something else (I would assume to something that's not already level 5). Then, level them up again to level 5. Keep doing this process until hardware engineer shows up on the list of job changes.

Comment: This is extremely interesting (and a little annoying that there's no clue that this is how it works).  I wonder if there is a hierarchy of job change possibilities then?

Comment: Yeah, it'd be cool to investigate.